# comparing two arraylist and taking the uncommon out in the second

Tags: java, arraylist

i have two lists

```
array A = [1,3,5]//jst array A
list B = [3,7]//ArrayList B
```

i want 7 out from list B

```
for(int A=0;A<elements.length;A++){
    for(int r=0;r<B.size();r++){
        if(A[k] != B.get(r)){
              pln(A[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Don't make us decode your code and understand the issue.

Comment: Is this a question or you want us to code for you?

Comment: What is "k" in A[k] and pln

Comment: Please use proper coding standards variable name should not start with caps character `A` is not valid. Use `indexA` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make the outer loop iterate over the list (B) and check for each element of B, if it is a member of the array. It's simply the other way round.

```
// for each element of B ...
for (i = 0; i < B.size(); i++ ) {
  // ... check each element of A
  for (j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
     // if it is equal.
     if (B.get(i) == A[j]) {
         // if yes, continue with the next B
         break; 
     }
  }
  // so none of the elements of A matched the element of B.
  System.out.println(B.get(i));
}
```

*Note: the variable names violate java conventions. I only kept your names to help you understand the answer. Please use spelling names that that start with lower case characters. The Commodore 64 Basic times are over*

Answer (score 1):

This should do it quickly:

```
B.retainAll(Arrays.asList(elements));
```

Assuming `B` is a `List`, and `elements` - an array.

Comment: Simply removes the uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Not the cleanest but it works:

```
final Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5 };
final Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[] { 3, 7 };
List<Integer> arr2List = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
arr2List.retainAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));
System.out.println(arr2List); // output [3]
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't want to _remove_ the common, but retain them.

Comment: Thats not what it looks like to me, given his expected output. I could be misunderstanding his English though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList(); 
        a1.add(3);
        a1.add(4);
        a1.add(5);
        ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList(); 
        a2.add(3);
        a2.add(7);
        a2.retainAll(a1);
        for(Integer i:a2)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```